# hg: how do I view a file as it was at a particular revision?

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, I can do

```
hg glog templates/base.html
```

to see the complete revision history for a file.

How can I view the file as it was at, say, changeset 1000?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hg cat -r 1000 templates/base.html
```